# Alternative to using shared_from_this() in a constructor of a base class

Tags: c++, c++14, software-design

This question is somewhat related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959193/how-to-declare-factory-like-method-in-base-class), but not the same... please don't refer me to it...

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73354900/clang-tidy-calling-a-base-constructor-other-than-the-copy-constructor) I asked (a different question) about a class similar to this one:

```
#include <memory>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class Base : public enable_shared_from_this<Base>
{
public:
    explicit Base(Base *parent = nullptr) : parent(parent) { parent->children.insert(shared_from_this()); }

private:
    Base *parent; // weak pointer
    set<shared_ptr<Base>> children;
};
```

Some of the responds mentioned (correctly) that I can't use `shared_from_this()` in the constructor.

I read about this issue that the best solution (short of using `boost::intrusive_ptr`) would be to use a static factory method instead of a constructor but my base class is actually virtual so my code turns out this way:

```
#include <memory>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class Base : public enable_shared_from_this<Base>
{
protected:
    Base() {};
    void SetParent(Base *_parent)
    {
        parent = _parent;
        parent->children.insert(shared_from_this());
    }

private:
    Base *parent = nullptr;
    set<shared_ptr<Base>> children;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    static Derived *Create(Base *parent = nullptr)
    {
        Derived *obj = new Derived();
        if (parent) obj->SetParent(parent);
        return obj;
    }

private:
    Derived() : Base() {};
};
```

However, this would force me to write boilerplate code for every child class, therefore the natural evolution would be to write it as a template factory at the base class, but since I want the derived class constructor to be private (to force using the static factory) I have to declare the base class as a friend in the derived class, resulting that the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class Base : public enable_shared_from_this<Base>
{
public:
    template<typename T> static T* Create(Base *parent = nullptr)
    {
        T *obj = new T();
        if (parent) obj->SetParent(parent);
        return obj;
    }

protected:
    Base() {};
    void SetParent(Base *_parent)
    {
        parent = _parent;
        parent->children.insert(shared_from_this());
    }

private:
    Base *parent = nullptr;
    set<shared_ptr<Base>> children;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
    friend class Base;
    Derived() : Base() {};
};
```

So my question is... is there a more elegant way to do this (preferably shorter and without boost and friend classes)...?

Comment: Orthogonal: in the static `T* Create(..)`, assert that `T` is a descendant of `Base`.

Comment: Is it for a tree? Consider changing the logic. Usually children share a single parent, not parents share a single child.

Comment: Do you expect any of `children` to outlive `parent`? If not, parent can simply own children.

Comment: Also, `Create()` should return `shared_ptr<>` I think. And the way you proposed limits you to have the exact same ctor arguments in each descendant; that's very limiting, I think I'd rather go with one `create()` function per descendant.

Comment: @273K this is for a tree-like structure but I'm not sure what you mean... the children do have a single parent and the parents have multiple children as implied by `parent->children.insert(shared_from_this());`

Comment: @lorro I'm not sure what you mean by "parent can simply own children"... that is the intention but I want to add elements to the parent when creating the child and not by calling some method of the parent object.

Comment: @lorro I agree with your 2nd comment in general but in this specific case there aren't any different arguments in the constructors.

Comment: @traveh If children are destructed when parents are destructed, then you can have `std::vector<Base*>` in your base class and simply delete those in dtor. No need for `shared_ptr<>`'s overhead.

Comment: Just try to ask yourself. Is children w/o a parent legit? If no, why then you make such relation possible? Children should have shared pointers to their parents, so parents outlive their children.

Comment: @273 of course nodes without parents are legit - first of all, there is the root of the tree, but I also might be storing them for later use or pass them around (they contain important data that take overhead to create).

Comment: Your comment only confirms that it should be `std::shared_ptr<Base> parent;
    std::set<Base*> children;`

Comment: @273K I'm not sure I understand why... if the references (the shared pointers) will be from the tree leaves to the root then I would have to hold a reference somewhere to every leaf (e.g. in some kind of shared_ptr array) otherwise as soon as I exit the function that allocated the leaf it would be freed (causing a chain reaction)...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it - and it is **controversial**. Be warned. It is a simpler version of intrusives but it has its value. Take it for what's worth it.

First you define a base class with a counter inside. If your code is not expected to be multithreaded, you dont need the atomic for speed.

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
struct ReferenceCounter {
    std::atomic<int> counter;
};
```

Then create a base class based on that reference counted class. It has a vector (not a set) for children. (If you add a child twice, shouldnt it be double ref counted?). The purpose of the virtual inheritance is to avoid the dreaded [diamond problem](https://www.makeuseof.com/what-is-diamond-problem-in-cpp/).

```cpp
class Base : public virtual ReferenceCounter
{
public:
...
private:
    Base *parent = nullptr;
    std::vector<Base*> children;
};
```

The default constructor will take a Base pointer. I simplified away your `Create` static method - sorry, you can put it back it's not a problem.

```cpp
    Base( Base* parent ) {
        std::cout << "Creating object " << this << " with parent " << parent << std::endl;
        if (parent!=nullptr) { 
            SetParent(parent);
        }
    }
```

The destructor will traverse all the children and decrement all their reference counters. If any gets to zero, delete it.

```cpp
    virtual ~Base() {
        std::cout << "Erasing object " << this << std::endl;
        for ( Base* ptr : children ) {
            ptr->counter--;
            if ( ptr->counter == 0 ) {
                delete ptr;
            }
        }        
        if ( parent!=nullptr ) {
            parent->RemoveChild( this );
        }
    }
```

Then comes the machinery to add children properly

```cpp
protected:
    void addChild( Base* ptr ) {
        if ( ptr != nullptr ) {
            ptr->counter++;
            children.push_back( ptr );
        }
    }
    void SetParent(Base *_parent)
    {
        parent = _parent;
        parent->addChild( this );
    }
    void RemoveChild( Base* ptr ) {
        for ( size_t j=0; j<children.size(); ++j ) {
            if ( children[j]==ptr ) {
                children.erase( std::remove_if( children.begin(),children.end(), 
                                [ptr]( Base* child ) { return child==ptr; }));
            }
        }
    }
```

Then there is minimal boilerplate in the derived classes.

```cpp
class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
    Derived( Base* parent = nullptr ) : Base(parent) {}
};
```

Beware this mechanism will leak if there is cyclic references.

You can run some tests to see if it works:

```cpp
void test1() {
    std::cout << ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Test 1" << std::endl;
    Derived* parent = new Derived();
    Derived* d1 = new Derived( parent );
    Derived* d2 = new Derived( d1 );
    Derived* d3 = new Derived( d2 );
    std::cout << "Deleting parent" << std::endl;
    delete parent;
}
```

Produces

```bash
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Test 1
Creating object 0xaadec0 with parent 0
Creating object 0xaadf00 with parent 0xaadec0
Creating object 0xaadf60 with parent 0xaadf00
Creating object 0xaadfc0 with parent 0xaadf60
Deleting parent
Erasing object 0xaadec0
Erasing object 0xaadf00
Erasing object 0xaadf60
Erasing object 0xaadfc0
```

And another test, now with a hierarchical topology where one child is deleted

```cpp
void test2() {
    std::cout << ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Test 2" << std::endl;
    Derived* parent = new Derived();
    Derived* d1 = new Derived( parent );
    Derived* d2 = new Derived( d1 );
    Derived* d3 = new Derived( d2 );
    std::cout << "Deleting d2" << std::endl;
    delete d2;
    std::cout << "Deleting parent" << std::endl;
    delete parent;
}
```

Produces

```bash
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Test 2
Creating object 0xaadec0 with parent 0
Creating object 0xaadf00 with parent 0xaadec0
Creating object 0xaadf60 with parent 0xaadf00
Creating object 0xaadfc0 with parent 0xaadf60
Deleting d2
Erasing object 0xaadf60
Erasing object 0xaadfc0
Deleting parent
Erasing object 0xaadec0
Erasing object 0xaadf00
```

I put the entire code on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PM6zYrzvY)